# Using Jquery to post single variable

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I have a jquery function which prompts user to enter a value in a dialog box and posts the value to a script and then returns a value which posts a form value if the first value is correct. The second value (txtImport) is not being posted to the script (importFile)?

Answer (score 0):

I found two errors on you JS.

you cannot use the following line:

`"setCompany.php", { COMPANY_NAME : COMPANY_NAME.val() }`

it should be

`$(COMPANY_NAME).val()`

Reason being is that `COMPANY_NAME.val()` will just return nothing in most cases or blank string. **It is NOT a JQuery object**.

The second error is the same:

`$.post("importFile.php", { txtImport : txtImport.val() }`

Use `$(txtImport).val()` instead. For the same reason.